# ExpandableListView

Tags: android

ExpandableListView как поменять цвет текста?

Comment: в каком смысле? ExpdandableListView это контейнер, там цвета текста нет. Есть текст во вьюхах (если там есть поля с текстом), которые вы биндите. А как поменять текст цвета в TextView я думаю вы знаете.

Answer (score 1):

Свой адаптер лучше написать, или вытащить TextView и поменять цвет, как-то так

```
TextView tv = (TextView)expandableListView.findById(android.R.id.textview1);
tv.setTextColor(Color.RED);
```

как сделать свой [тут](http://habrahabr.ru/post/147546/)

Answer (score 1):

Вот пример [как можно изменить](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7765878/change-text-color-in-expandedlistview-when-list-is-expanded) цвет текста для группы